# how to Detect Collision and Remove body and image after Collision

Tags: java, android, collision-detection, andengine, game-physics

I am new on AndEngine and trying to detect collisions and destroy the body on collision. So far I have tried this.

```
 if (testingsprite.collidesWith(testingSprite1)) {
                Log.d("TAG", "Collisoion");
                mphysicworld.destroyBody(myBody);
                scene.detachChild(testingSprite1);
                myBody = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(this.mphysicworld,
                        testingSprite1, BodyType.DynamicBody, FIXTURE_DEF);
            }else{
                Log.d("TAG", "else Collisoion");
            }

`
```

But it does not work, and always goes into the else part. What should I do? I have tried with contactListener to but it become too messy and difficult to control. I am currently working with eclipse and physicsbox2dextention in andengine.

Comment: well, contact listeners are the way to go and if it becomes too messy then that's a code structure/design problem of yours I'm afraid. But without seeing that code we can't tell you how to "unmess" it.

Comment: read here http://www.matim-dev.com/handling-collisions-between-bodies.html

Comment: thnkxxx alot @Cristian Olaru.. that works for... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a new "ContactListener" and bind it to your "PhysicsWorld"
By "physicsWorldInstance.setContactListener(...)"

and in the ContactListener override "beginContact". for example:

```
public void beginContact(Contact contact)
    {
        final Fixture x1 = contact.getFixtureA();
        final Fixture x2 = contact.getFixtureB();

        if (x2.getBody().getUserData().equals("player")&&x1.getBody().getUserData().equals("monster"))
        {
          Log.d("TAG", "Collisoion");
        }

    }
```

Comment: jumpy yes i have already done that with that..but as i am not able to answer so ..i accept yours...as you also recommended me correct answer!